# Upgrading Redux framework on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, frameworks, upgrade, redux-framework

I'm new to Wordpress, and in my plugin page I see Redux asking for upgrade.

---

A new build of Redux is now available!
Your version: 3.3.0.1
New version: 3.3.7.8

### Get it now  |  Dismiss.

However unlike other plugins, it doesn't have any easy places to upload a zip or something. By clicking "Get it now", it simply takes me to its Github, where a bunch of code base exist, but again no instruction on how it can be quickly updated to the latest. Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sigh* Lead dev of Redux here. Looks like the developer of your theme/plugin shipped with dev_mode on. That's not good. Let's get you setup.

I just created a plugin to disable this. Go here and install the zip as a plugin (and activate it): https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-disable-devmode    (This will be on the WordPress Plugins Directory soon).

Then go to the WordPress repo and install the newest Redux Framework: http://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework/

That will get you all you need! Best of luck.

Comment: Works perfectly now, thanks a lot for the support Dovy!